# Вывести информацию с массива в view

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
`Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 14287
        [sum_date] => 21.06.2017 (00:00)
        [sum_payment_6] => 229.375
        [model] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SSB-2359
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 14159
        [date_added] => 15.06.2017 (11:29)
        [sum_payment_5] => -17193.7
        [model] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0801
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SKA068-1006-0827
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SSB-1006-0490
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0807
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SK-1030-0028
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SK-1094-0010
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0803
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SKPAK-1006-0805
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SK-1030-0033
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [model] => SK-1030-0030
                    )

            )

    )
)`
```

Мне нужно вывести в view название модели?

Comment: дак выведите. Или если у вас с этим проблема, то так и напишите в чем именно она заключается.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы просто не знаете как обработать многомерный массив, то вот код который выводит то что вам нужно.

```
<?php

    $arr; // Это ваш массив

    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($arr[$i]['model']);$j++){
            echo '<span class="model">'.$arr[$i]['model'][$j]['model'].'</span>';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: циклы `foreach` использовать не пробовали?

Comment: @teran вопрос кому?

Comment: вам. такой вывод гораздо удобнее делать с `foreach` циклом, ибо писать `$arr[$i]['model'][$j]['model']` это какой то лютый треш.

Comment: @teran Не кто не мешает вам дать свой вариант ответа, вместо того что бы комментировать впустую. Вариантов много, и это один из правильных.

Comment: нет никакого смысла плодить одинаковые ответы с разным синтаксисом. на практике при наличии циклов `foreach` циклы `for` весьма редко используются. Поэтому ваш выбор несколько странный, на что я и обратил внимание, в т.ч. тех, кто будет читать ваш ответ. для этого комментарии и существуют

Comment: @teran если считаете ваш ответ правильнее то дайте ответ, для того и есть возможность дать много ответов на один вопрос. А если бы циклы `for` не использовались, и были чем то не правильными то в `php` они бы уже были `deprecated` или в последних версиях их удалили бы вообще.

Comment: @teran И еще одно можете посмотреть время работы `for` и `foreach`, и где какой использовать.

Comment: да мне мотивацию вашего выбора просто интересно понять. когда можно написать просто `$m['model']` вы написали, то что написали. Может вы руководствуетесь какими то критериями о которых я не знаю, например, мб что читали где-то, что циклы `for` более эффективны, либо просто любите писать сложный код.

Comment: @teran `foreach` работает долго чем `for`.

Comment: во, вот этого я от вас и ожидал услышать, обоснование такого кода, а не отсыл лесом. еще лучше бы со ссылками

Comment: [первая ссылка из гугла](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216103/), правда говорит  несколько об обратном.

Comment: `foreach` лучше работает с массивами, вообще с итерациями)